# Forward declaring enum in C header included in C++

Tags: c++, c, linkage

I have C headers which forward declare enums.  Apparently, this is not possible in C++, so all of the pre-processor wraps of the form

```
extern "C" {
  #include <header.h>
}
```

are not going to help.  Is there any way to include these headers in a C++ translation unit without requiring me to edit the C headers?  Fortunately, modifying the C headers to avoid the forward declaration in this case is relatively painless, but this strikes me as being a pretty significant problem.  In general, I had thought it was always possible to link against a C library from C++, but the inability to include the header seems to make that impractical in some cases.

Somewhat related questions:
[71416](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71416/forward-declaring-an-enum-in-c)
[681243](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681243/in-c-how-can-i-avoid-including-a-header-file-when-i-need-to-use-an-enumeratio)

Comment: that should work according to here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0603949d(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forward declared enums are available in C++0x. If your compiler doens't support it yet, then wrapping enums in namespaces will avoid violation of ODR.

P.S. a good explanation: http://www.devx.com/cplus/Article/42478/1954?pf=true